# Statment is not a valid Name Space while converting vb6 to vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

```
Public Function fnGetNextMaxNo(ByVal strFieldName As String) As Integer

    fnGetNextMaxNo = 0
    Dim adoRs As VbToRecordSet
    Dim strSql As String = ""
    Try
        fnGetNextMaxNo = 1

        strSql = "select max(" + strFieldName + ") from " + strTableName
        mstrLastExecutedSql = strSql
        adoRs.Open(strSql, adoconDb)
        If Not adoRs.EOF Then
            If Not IsDBNull(adoRs.Fields(0).Value) Then
                fnGetNextMaxNo = Convert.toDouble(adoRs.Fields(0).Value) + 1
            End If
        End If

        adoRs.Close()
        Exit Function
```

I am trying to convert vb6 to vb.net ,The above code first line shows error that statement is not valid in name space...Please help me

Answer (score 0):

just replace

```
Dim adoRs As VbToRecordSet
```

with

```
 Dim adoRs As adodb.RecordSet
```